# Firebase + Twitter OAuth on Android doesn't work anymore

Tags: android, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

Few months ago I integrated Firebase + Twitter OAuth in my Android app.
Recently I was refactoring the app and noticed that Firebase + Twitter authentication, which was properly tested earlier, doesn't work anymore on all my devices and with different accounts. 
I was trying numerous workarounds since then, such as:

- completely re-create the app in Twitter Dev console;
- set ONLY ***twittersdk://*** as callback URL in Twitter Dev console;
- check all Twitter / Firebase manuals once more and make sure that project has all the necessary code;
- initialize Twitter SDK in different ways (see below) etc.

I don't see any reason to list any auth-related code here because it's quite similar to general samples and snippets such as 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login?authuser=0 and 
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Getting-Started and https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Log-In-with-Twitter . 
And, surely, all of it was tested when Twitter + Firebase auth worked.

The exceptions I get depend on the way of initializing Twitter SDK.

For example, when I initialize Twitter in Application's `onCreate()` like this:

```
Twitter.initialize(this)
```

I get

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. 
[ Failed to get successful verify_credentials response:{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]} ]
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzds.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzew.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeo.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdy.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Also, when I initialize Twitter in Application's `onCreate()` like this:

```
val config = TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(TwitterAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET"))
                .debug(true)
                .build()
Twitter.initialize(config)
```

I get

```
E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:98)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:143)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(TwitterLoginButton.java:131)
        at com.kkaun.mediator.ui.user.login.providers.TwitterSignInActivity.onActivityResult(TwitterSignInActivity.kt:90)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6572)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3757)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)

W/TwitterSignInActivity: twitterLogin:failure
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:98)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:143)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(TwitterLoginButton.java:131)
        at com.kkaun.mediator.ui.user.login.providers.TwitterSignInActivity.onActivityResult(TwitterSignInActivity.kt:90)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6572)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3757)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

---

As we all know, Twitter discontinued support for Twitter Kit on October 31, 2018, as mentioned here https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html.
So I wonder, could this fact be the cause of my issue?